# why wont this jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div style="width:600px;">
<p id="web" >Web </p>
<p id="webd" >description of web based services and what not more stuff more stuff more stuff 
more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff 
more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff 
more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff 
more stuff more stuff more stuff more stuff 
</p>
</div>



<script>
  $("#web")click(function () {
    alert('You clicked');
    $("#webd").slideToggle("slow");
  });

</script>
```

I have this jquery code that im trying to run, the lquery lib are included but it just refuses to run. what am i doing wrong ?
found it ! there was a dot missing... this has been fing with me all day !!!

Comment: I assume the lack of a dot in `$("#web")click` is a typo?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { <Your script here>});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#web")click(function () {
```

should be

```
$("#web").click(function () {
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error at   `$("#web")click`. It should be   `$("#web").click`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the <p> tag offers a click event. You probably want to do a mouseup event.

Comment: You can listen for any event on any element, even if it is nonsensical to do so.  For instance, you can add an event listener for clicks on the `head` element, even though it is logically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "." (dot) after "$('#web')"  --- right before the click() call.